# BLOCK frequently occurs Groovy multithreading capabilities of mixin

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, mixins

When I use groovy mixin function of the case of multi-threaded , most use mixin thread occurrence block.

- Groovy Version `2.4.6`
- Java Version `1.7`

A small example reproducing the problem:

```
class ClassMixinTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100)

    while (true) {
        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            void run() {
                invoke()
            }
        })

        service.submit()

    }
}

static void invoke() {
    ClassMixinTest.User user = new ClassMixinTest.User()

    long start = System.nanoTime()

    user.metaClass.mixin(ClassMixinTest.Man)

    println("spend" + (System.nanoTime() - start))

}


static class User {
}

static class Man {
}

}
```

Run the exmple `ClassMixinTest` and analysis using `jstack` thread stacks,and then we found a large amount of obstruction occurs now in the implementation of mixin.

- A detailed thread stacks
  [image]

BLOCK found that have occurred in the same place:`org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface`

- this method
  [image]

Does anyone know this place Why synchronize or how can I avoid the block, when I use mixin in multiple threads .

Comment: wow, I couldn't work around the deadlock even when doing the mixin in a single thread! Something going terribly wrong but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Looks like there's already a number of bugs related to metamodel deadlocks: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5661?jql=text%20~%20%22metaclass%20deadlock%22

Comment: @Renato Have you tried in the multi thread ? Single thread I have not encountered a deadlock here。

Comment: Just I also feedback the problem to JIRA
：https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7811

Comment: I tried using your exact code, except I used a singleThreaded executor to call the mixin method in... and it still deadlocks.

Comment: @RenatoR 
Your position is in deadlock : `org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface` it?

Comment: @Renato 
Such terror, I replaced the groovy version to `2.3.7` , the problem is resolved

Comment: I cannot reproduce the deadlock. I see the blocks, but the program still continues. The problem with Switchpoint is, that is not made for frequent use. Invalidating a switchpoint means to reach a stop-the-world synchronization point in the JVM.  mixing in a class must call invalidateSwitchpoints, or else the callsite caching might be wrong.  So all in all I see it as wrong to mixin that often. We could maybe add in an optimization that recognizes a reoccurring case like the one above. But we are moving away from mixin and plan to deprecate it in the long term.

Comment: oh... I just noticed Java 1.7.. There are some extremely buggy version of Java 1.7 out there. Please ensure you are using one of the newest ones